# How can I print a switch's ON/OFF state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

As given in this example: https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch.html
I am trying to print the ON/OFF state of Switch in something like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Switch, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
  const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor={isEnabled ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
      />
      <Text> Switch state is: {isEnabled} </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```

But, it doesn't print `{isEnabled}` value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for toggling the state looks fine - I think the issue is more subtle. Boolean values don't get rendered in jsx - see reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored

Can you try converting `isEnabled` to a string before rendering it?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here. `setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);`

It should be `setIsEnabled(!previousState)`

The methods used for setting states just take a value as an argument, not a function.

Comment: setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState) is right, you can pass the value or a callback function. Here you can find more info about it https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know.

Comment: And this code as-is makes no sense anyway; there is no "previousState" variable unless you use the function version.